# Engine whine / whir noise while revving Rav4

Tags: engine, toyota, noise, rav4

Rav4 2013 2.5 2AR-FE

I noticed that there is a constant whirring noise that seems to match the engine speed. It doesn't matter if it is in neutral, drive, reverse, park etc. The sound seems to pretty much remain the same, tied to the RPMs (Seems louder on cold starts).

Here is the Audio:  [https:youtu.be/YkX_zckZJV8](https://youtu.be/YkX_zckZJV8)

How can I diagnose the problem?

UPDATE: Today I removed the alternator belt and started engine to check if it was any pulleys.  However noise was still there.  Now I'm sure it comes from engine. :( Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!